# $.each & setTimeOut Issue - TimeOut isn't clearing

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

```
var TimeOut; //Global
$('[name^="HMapDot"]').each(function(i){
    TimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        $('[name^="HMapDot"]').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
        $('#HMapTime').html($('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').attr('role')+' [ '+(i+1)+' ]');
        $('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    },i * iTime);
    if(i == (iMany-1) || $('[name^="HMapDot"]').length == 0){ clearTimeout(TimeOut); return false; }
});
```

I have this code working just fine, using JQuery 2.x and AJAX to pull data.  My intention was to delay the dot on the "map" to appear/disappear every second (slider values).  Now when I click on "Stop", the page, values, element will be $.remove, but the timer will continued to be counted down.  How do I stop the timer and $.each?

Modified code below that works:

```
var TimeOuts = []; //Global
var T;
function ClearTimeOuts(){
    for(var i in TimeOuts){
        clearTimeout(TimeOuts[i]);
    }
}
$('[name^="HMapDot"]').each(function(i){
    T = setTimeout(function(){
        $('[name^="HMapDot"]').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
        $('#HMapTime').html($('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').attr('role')+' [ '+(i+1)+' ]');
        $('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').css({'visibility':'visible'});
        if(i == (iMany-1) || $('[name^="HMapDot"]').length == 0){ 
            ClearTimeOuts(); 
            return false;
        }
    },i * iTime);
    TimeOuts.push(T);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the `setTimeout` inside of `each` - you need an array to store and stop timeout handles:

```
var TimeOuts = []; //Global
function ClearTimeOuts(){
    for(var i in TimeOuts){
        clearTimeout(TimeOuts[i]);
    }
}
$('[name^="HMapDot"]').each(function(i){
    var T = setTimeout(function(){
        $('[name^="HMapDot"]').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
        $('#HMapTime').html($('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').attr('role')+' [ '+(i+1)+' ]');
        $('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    },i * iTime);
    if(i == (iMany-1) || $('[name^="HMapDot"]').length == 0){ 
        ClearTimeOuts(); 
        return false;
    }
    TimeOuts.push(T);
});
```

Comment: this one sorta works, but when I use this code, it will not display anything until the END of the dots.  Still tinkering.

Comment: ok, found the issue with this one.  Because if(i == (iMany-1) || $('[name^="HMapDot"]').length == 0){ ClearTimeOuts(); return false; } was outside of the timer, the setTimeout doesn't know when it ends, so I moved that line INSIDE the setTimeout, it exited gracefully when I press stop button.  Many thanks for leading me to the right direction!  See above for modified code that worked!

Answer (score 0):

All your dots share the same variable for keeping track of the timer, so each one will overwrite the previous. You need one variable for each dot.

Declare the variable inside the function, that will create a local variable for each dot:

```
$('[name^="HMapDot"]').each(function(i){
    var TimeOut;
    TimeOut = setTimeout(function(){
        $('[name^="HMapDot"]').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
        $('#HMapTime').html($('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').attr('role')+' [ '+(i+1)+' ]');
        $('[name="HMapDot'+i+'"]').css({'visibility':'visible'});
    },i * iTime);
    if(i == (iMany-1) || $('[name^="HMapDot"]').length == 0){ clearTimeout(TimeOut); return false; }
});
```